# Looking for the complete game Sibilio-Mariotti, Ravenna 1982

Tags: draw, stalemate, famous-games

Tim Krabbe shows this game on his [record site](http://timkr.home.xs4all.nl/records/records.htm).

```
[Title "Sibilio-Mariotti, Ravenna 1982"]
[FEN "5k2/1p4pp/4p3/3pP1q1/3P4/7K/7P/8 w - - 0 1"]
```

The game has a stalemate after only 27 moves. I would like to know the complete game. I did not find in chessgames.com, chess365, or my database. Does anybody know the full game?

Comment: www.youtube.com/watch?v=5pebuJFQAls

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_world_records_in_chess#Shortest_stalemate

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All games from Tim Krabbe's website are available in the little player on the right side of the page (there is a chessboard, game navigation bar and a box from which the games can be chosen).
For the sake of the question and since it is quite an entertaining game, though:

```
[White "Sibilio"]
[Black "Mariotti"]
[Event "Ravenna 1982"]
[fen "rnbqkbnr/pppppppp/8/8/8/8/PPPPPPPP/RNBQKBNR w KQkq - 0 1"]

1. e4 e6 2. Nf3 d5 3. e5 c5 4. b4 cxb4 5. d4 Nh6 6. a3 bxa3 7. c3 Nf5 8. Nxa3 Nc6 9. Nb5 a6 10. g4 Bd7 11. Bg5 Be7 12. gxf5 axb5 13. fxe6 fxe6 14. Rxa8 Qxa8 15. Rg1 Qa3 16. Bxb5 Bxg5 17. Rxg5 Qxc3+ 18. Kf1 O-O 19. Bxc6 Bxc6 20. Kg2 Ba4 21. Qe2 Bc2 22. Ne1 Bxe4+ 23. f3 Rxf3 24. Nxf3 Bxf3 25. Qxf3 Qd2+ 26. Kh3 Qxg5 27. Qf8+ Kxf8 1/2-1/2
```

Comment: Thank you very much! An additional question : f3 is stated as a stalemate trap. Could black have won after f3 and if yes, how ?

Comment: I saw the player, but I could not find this game, only the very long games.

Comment: @Peter - the game is there, I assure you; that's where I copied the moves from. :) As for the additional question, I think after 23. f3, black can simply play 23. .. Bg6. The d4 (and subsequently e5 pawn) will most likely fall (perhaps at a cost of b7 pawn) and black should be able to bring home the material, space and activity advantage. Another plan could be to defend b7 pawn and try to advance it. In any case, black has very good chances of winning after avoiding the stalemate trap. You may want to confirm my assertions with an engine, though...

Comment: Now, I also found it! I dragged the mouse but no more games appeared. But when I used the down-arrow-key, it worked. Anyway, thanks for your efforts.